# Scanner and parsing a CSV file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a simple CSV file in the format of below.

```
Company,Name,12,13,18
Company,Name,12,13,18
Company,Name,12,13,18
Company,Name,12,13,18
Company,Name,12,13,18
```

I'm trying to parse the all of the tokens and attempting to use `next()` and `nextInt()`. Following code throws an exception on the last token of each line (so the value 18 in this instance, last nextInt call). The exception is an `InputMismatchException`.

I'm struggling to understand why its a mismatch - I've checked there isn't anything funky going on with the CSV too such as whitespace.

My code is follows.

```java
public void readFile(String Path) {

    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(Paths.get(Path)).useDelimiter(",");
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
     
            while (sc.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(sc.next());
                System.out.println(sc.next());
                System.out.println(sc.nextInt());
                System.out.println(sc.nextInt());
                System.out.println(sc.nextInt());
            }
        
            sc.close();
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Cannot find file: " + Path);
    }
}
```

Is my understanding correct in that the first while loop will look at each line and the second while loop will look at each token separated by a comma?

Comment: What exception do you receive and what's the stacktrace?

Comment: what if you just try with `next()` to see what it actually reads?

Comment: @randommm with the first or second while statement?

Comment: To replace the nextInt that throws the error

Comment: I get a java.util.NoSuchElementException on the second iteration of next(). I presume that is when it is hitting the int although i would have thought it would convert it to String.

Comment: To add to me previous comment, it does actually print out all of the required information when changing them all to next()

Comment: The problem is your separator: when you change the separator of your scanner to `","` the line delimiter is no longer used as separator for `next()` / `nextInt()`. Therefore the "last" column of your first input line is actually read as "18\nCompany" which is not a valid integer value. If you try to read a CSV file without using a specialised library I would suggest to use a `BufferedReader` to read lines from the CSV file and only use a `Scanner` to split the the contents of a line.

Comment: @ThomasKläger is right. You'd be better off making a bean, say `CompanyInfo` to make an instance of itself with a `static CompanyInfo fromCsv(String line)` method. If you give an indication of what your fields mean, we can say more

Comment: Why don't you use `Files.readAllLines(Path pathToCsvFile)` or stream the lines with `Files.lines()`? That way you don't have to take care of linebreaks.

Answer (score 1):

Combining my comment with what @deHaar said:

```
public static List<CompanyInfo> readFile(String path) throws IOException {
    return Files.lines(Path.of(path)).
        map(CompanyInfo::fromCsv).
        collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: This is the best option for large files, because streaming those won't pollute the RAM. [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76164552/1712135) is sufficient for smaller csv files.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `java.nio` (`Path`), that means you could as well use other classes from that package. To read the lines of a file, there's `File.readAllLines()`, which returns a `List<String>` with each item representing a line. Having this list, you can start splitting the lines in a loop or a stream.

Here's an example:

#### Example CSV

```
Company One,Supercompany,12,9,18
Company Two,Ultracompany,13,10,19
Company Three,Megacompany,14,11,20
Company Four,Godlike Company,15,12,21
Company Five,Best Company,16,13,22
```

#### Java Code

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // path to your file (ATTENTION: dummy path, might not exist on your system)
    Path pathToCsvFile = Paths.get("/some/absolute/path/to/companies.csv");

    try {
        // read all the lines
        Files.readAllLines(pathToCsvFile).forEach(line -> {
            // split the content of each line by comma
            String[] lineParts = line.split(",");
            // and join the parts to a new String using a different delimiter
            System.out.println(String.join(" -- ", lineParts));
        });
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // handle errors (this is just a dummy output, might not be sufficient!)
        throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Reading " + pathToCsvFile.toAbsolutePath().toString() 
                    + " did not work, Reason: " + e1.getMessage()
        );
    }
```

#### Output

```
Company One -- Supercompany -- 12 -- 9 -- 18
Company Two -- Ultracompany -- 13 -- 10 -- 19
Company Three -- Megacompany -- 14 -- 11 -- 20
Company Four -- Godlike Company -- 15 -- 12 -- 21
Company Five -- Best Company -- 16 -- 13 -- 22
```